# Разбиение дисков

Tags: linux, windows, установка

Господа, ставлю Linux и столкнулся с проблемой. Как посоветуйте разбить диск для установки Linux, если в будущем я собираюсь установить вторую систему Windows. И каких типов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Развитие убунту прекращено. Имеет ли смысл ставить неперспективную версию Linux,

Comment: @Leroi почему прекращено ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. sda1 в ntfs на 100Gb. Метка "system".
2. sda2 в ext4 на 20-50Gb. Метка "linux".
3. extended на всё остальное.
4. Внутри ниего 4Gb в swap.
5. sda6 в ext4 на 20-50Gb. Метка "home".
6. sda7 в ntfs на всё остальное. Метка "data".

Я обычно винты разбиваю именно так и ничего ещё нигде не ломалось.

Да, файлики забэкапь, прежде чем будешь двигать разделы.

Comment: Согласен с такой рекомендацией. Одна тонкость: "Дружественный к пользователю" виндовоз, в процессе установки не видит ничего, кроме себя, любимого. Поэтому затрёт загрузчик Linux. А поэтому, рекомендую сначала поставить виндовоз в раздел 1 (ntfs- system) а потом - люних. Он всё сделает аккуратно.

Comment: @Sergey, а, ну да. Именно в такой последовательности. Я забыл написать. А даже если и затрёт - восстановить не особо сложно, если есть supergrubdisk или типа того.

Comment: Какой основной, какой расширенный?! В наше время GPT во всю!

Comment: @0andriy, ага. Покажешь мне винты на 3+Tb, которые покупают все кому не лень? А ещё очень классно, когда тебе приносят винт со словами "у меня тут немного разделы сдвинулись. можешь файлы вытащить?" и ты монаешься с testdisk и вытаскиваешь файлы, потому что остальные проги с gpt в 2015-2016 всё ещё дружили лишь на бумаге. В общем ненене, я пока так.

Comment: GPT не имеет (почти никакого) отношения к размеру диска.

Comment: @0andriy хранить код на винте без которого ОС отказывается грузиться - одна из тупейших идей, которую я видел в IT.

Comment: Вы поняли, что вы написали? То есть хранить саму ОС на винчестере -- одна из тупейших идей?

Comment: @0andriy, да. Вполне. ОС можно переставить, если винт навернётся, но если поиметь сертификат (это я щас про связку gpt+uefi) или как он там называется - просто накатить винду на планшет (ковырялись с asus) не получается. Какие ещё преимущества? Ну кроме поддержки uefi и 3tb+?

Comment: Вы мешаете в кучу какие-то совершенно разные вещи: GPT (это просто про модель разбиения диски на разделы), UEFI (интерфейс взаимодествия firmware и кода, который запускается в окружении UEFI shell), какие-то сертификаты (это вообще о чём? Secure Boot?)...

Comment: @0andriy, перечитал. Да, смешал всё в кучу. Собсно если с нуля начать: не вижу никаких преимуществ gpt, если винты до 3тб. Это если касаться только разметки без привязки других технологий.

Comment: Будет время, почитайте https://habrahabr.ru/post/327572/

Comment: @0andriy, ок, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, разделы физически записываются на диск в том порядке, в котором он размечен (если я не прав - поправьте). Следовательно, чем выше раздел, тем ближе он к центру диска и тем быстрее считывающая головка получает к нему доступ.

По этой причине порядок должен быть таким:

1. Загрузочный раздел
2. Swap
3. Системные разделы в порядке важности для вас
4. Home
5. Всё остальное

Если планируете использовать убунту версии 17+, то swap не нужен.

Comment: Головка очень быстро движется

Comment: @Alex78191 да, но у центра диска данные считываются быстрее чем у краёв.

Comment: Для SSD это, разумеется, неактуально.